# How to get the list styles of paragraph in office js api

Tags: office-js

I am getting following error whenever I am trying to get the list property of paragraph in office app:

```js
{
    "name": "OfficeExtension.Error",
    "code": "ItemNotFound",
    "message": "We couldn’ t find the item you requested. Check the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information.",
    "traceMessages": [],
    "innerError": null,
    "debugInfo": {
        "code": "ItemNotFound ",
        "message": "We couldn’ t find the item you requested.Check the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information.",
        "errorLocation ": "Paragraph._onAccess "
    }
}
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```js
var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
context.load(paragraphs, 'style');
return context.sync().then(function () {
            var list = paragraphs.items[0].listOrNullObject;
            context.load(list);
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                var item = list.levelTypes;
                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    console.log("text" + item);
                });

            })
```

How to get the list styles of paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

You're not running within a `Word.run` context. Everything should be scoped within this context or your objects won't populate.

To populate your paragraphs collection, try this:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
        var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
        context.load(paragraphs);
        return context.sync().then(function () {
             // Process paragraphs here
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am running the code in word.run context only and able to access paragraph properties.Problem I am facing to access the list related properties only where I got the above error.I am testing in online office 365.